# Is it better to create a new object and return it or create the new object in the return statement?

Tags: java

For example:

```
public Person newPerson() {
  Person p = new Person("Bob", "Smith", 1112223333);
  return p;
}
```

as opposed to:

```
public Person newPerson() {
  return new Person("Bob", "Smith", 1112223333);
}
```

Is one more efficient than the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assignment to a temporary variable before returning gives you a chance to do error checking and correction from within your newPerson(). Returning the new call requires the caller of your newPerson() method to catch and recover from errors.

Comment: If further access to the variable was being done, there would be no question as the scenario would no longer exist.

Comment: Really, I'd question the existence of this method altogether in a code review. A one line new*() routine to return a Person with some defaults? If you're not going to provide some additional functionality over the "new Person( )" call with your newPerson() routine, newPerson() is a method with limited usefulness IMO. Why not just have a:

public Person() {...}

constructor? Same thing without the method call layer.

They're equally poor choices for a method, but at least the first form gives you a chance to do something helpful for the user they wouldn't get calling new Person() on their own.

Comment: The method in this example is trivial. I prefer using simple examples over posting an actual method that I'm using in live code.

Comment: Also, even if that were the code (and currently it is trivial), the reason Factory methods are a valid design pattern is that later their implementation might drastically change. `newPerson` is not required to return a new object (and may return a subclass), while the constructer must return a new instance of `Person` which strays away from Java's interface-oriented design.

Answer (score 20):

There isn't any difference that would make you chose one over the other in terms of performance.

- For the sake of debugging, the former is better - i.e. when you want to trace the execution, or log some info between creation and returning.
- For the sake of readability (but this is subjective) - the latter is better.

In general, I'd advice for the latter, and whenever you need to debug this, make a temporary switch to the first (two-line) variant.

Comment: I'd argue that neither is more readable than the other, so why make a temporary switch? The code that the JIT compiler generates for either pattern is likely to be 100% identical. No difference. So if the first pattern has any advantage at all, however slight, why not just use it (or at least leave it once you've made the change)?

Comment: well, for me it's more readable to return it right away. But when tracing with a debugger it is far more convenient to have it in two lines. And perhaps log debugging info in between.

Comment: It comes down to if you're optimizing for readability or debugability, One could argue that code is read (by humans) far more than it's debugged.

Comment: Because it's more readable, so it's a trade-off, not a clear advantage. This is what engineering is.

Answer (score 1):

No one is not more efficient than the other, the JIT will inline it out to the most efficient at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

In a sane world, they will compile to exactly the same bytecode, so they are identical as far as performance is concerned. Then the only difference is for humans:

**Creating a temporary variable** makes debugging slightly easier: you can put a breakpoint on the return statement and inspect the value of `p`. In the one-line version, this is harder to do.

**Doing it in one line** eliminates a variable, reducing complexity, making the code slightly easier to read.

In practice, I would write it in one line, and in the worst case I create a temporary variable if I run into the debugging issue. Besides, aren't unit tests supposed to eliminate the need for debugging? :-)

Answer (score 0):

One is not more efficient than the other, but returning created object directly is probably cleaner since you're using less temporary variables. If you must use temporary variables, make it `final` and name it appropriately.

Comment: Please clarify where the temporary variables are.  I always though P is instantiated and a reference to P returned.  If you don't declar P an object is still instantiated and a reference passed.

Comment: java passes variables by VALUE it makes a copy of P and P falls out of scope at the return.

Comment: What @fuzzy said. A good compiler may optimize the implementation, but as far as the source code is concerned, `p` is a temporary variable. That's simply what it's called. Always has been, always will be.

Answer (score 0):

The second option is shorter and easier to read.

I doubt that any decent Java compiler would create less efficient code for the first option though.